# Discarding after picking up discard pile in Canasta

Tags: canasta

Today we had a situation.   Player legally picked up discard pile. All he had left in hand were dead cards and wild cards.  Is there a rule about which should be discarded first?

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule specifying what type of cards you discard so it is up to the player to decide if they want to discard a dead card or a wild card.

[Canasta Rules](http://www.canasta.net/canasta_rules.php)

> When a player has melded his cards, he ends his turn by discarding a card. At that point, his melded cards are checked to see if they conform to the canasta rules. Discarding a card is not necessary if the player can go out by melding all of his cards.